Why does the term disappear after applying Bayes formula?
The issue I am facing is directly related with the derivation of the Interactive Multiple Model (IMM) framework provided in the book "Estimation with applications to tracking navigation - Theory, Algorithms and Software" by Bar-Shalom, Li and Kirubarajan.
More specifically, the problem comes when calculating a conditional probability using Bayes formula. A few pages before, right at the beginning of the section where the Multiple Model approach is formulated (page 441), an analogous operation is carried out and the result is straightforward.

1. EASY OPERATION:
The aim of the Multiple Model approach is to perform target tracking (Bayesian filtering) combining different dynamic models that are (more or less) likely to fit the motion.
We denote by
$$
Z^k = \left\{z(i)\,|\,i=0,\dots,k\right\}\quad \forall k\geq 1
$$
the set of $k$ measurements (observations).
If there is a set of possible motion models $\{M_j\}_{j=1}^r,$ as stated by the authors, the posterior probability of model $j$ being correct, given the measurement data up to $k$, is given by the recursion:
$$
\mu_j(k) 
 \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=}
 P\!\left\{M_j\,|\,Z^k\right\} = P\!\left\{M_j\,|\,z(k), Z^{k-1}\right\}
=
\frac{p\!\left[z(k)\,|\,Z^{k-1},M_j\,\right]\,P\!\left\{M_j\,|\, Z^{k-1}\right\}}{p\!\left[z(k)\,|\, Z^{k-1}\right]}
$$
for all $j=1,\dots,r$.
To obtain the result, it suffices to apply Bayes formula consecutively, a couple of times:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\!\left\{M_j\,|\,z(k), Z^{k-1}\right\}
&=
\frac{p\!\left[z(k)\,|\,Z^{k-1},M_j\,\right]\,P\!\left\{Z^{k-1}, M_j\right\}}{P\!\left\{z(k), Z^{k-1}\right\}}
\\[3mm]
&=
p\!\left[z(k)\,|\,Z^{k-1},M_j\,\right]
\frac{P\!\left\{M_j\,|\, Z^{k-1}\right\}P\!\left\{Z^{k-1}\right\}}{p\left[z(k)\,|\,Z^{k-1}\right]P\!\left\{Z^{k-1}\right\}},
\end{aligned}
$$
and cancel the common terms.

2. QUESTION:
On the other hand, when deriving the posterior conditioned pdf of the state for the IMM (page 453), the authors write:
$$
p\!\left[x(k)\,|\,M_j, z(k), Z^{k-1}\right]
=
\frac{p\!\left[z(k)\,|\,M_j, x(k)\right]}{p[z(k)\,|\,M_j, Z^{k-1}]}
p\!\left[x(k)\,|\,M_j, Z^{k-1}\right].
$$
But, when trying to apply the same procedure as before, I get:
$$
p\!\left[x(k)\,|\,M_j, z(k), Z^{k-1}\right]
=
\frac{p\!\left[z(k)\,|\,M_j, x(k),\color{blue} {Z^{k-1}}\right]}{p[z(k)\,|\,M_j, Z^{k-1}]}
p\!\left[x(k)\,|\,M_j, Z^{k-1}\right].
$$
Why does that term vanish? I have thought about some independence premises, but that would impply more terms to disappear.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note that at time $k$, the value of $x(k)$ is known, hence at that time the state $Z^{k-1}$ is irrelevant in the sense that $P(z^k|x(k), Z^{k-1}) = P(z^k|x(k))$. In other words, for a given $x(k)$, $z^{k}$ and $Z^{k-1}$ are independent.
